Data separation, applying changes and finally combining the result
I have written a series of lengthy commands. I would like to learn how to condense them using a for loop or another concise command.
df.col.unique()

#array(['a', 'b',....,'x', 'y']



a = df[df.cal== "a"]

a['lesser_count']=np.sum(np.tril(np.subtract.outer(a.col2.values,a.cal2.values),k=0)<0,axis=1)

result_a=a[a.lesser_count > 0]

result_a



b = df[df.cal== "b"]

b['lesser_count']=np.sum(np.tril(np.subtract.outer(b.col2.values,b.cal2.values),k=0)<0,axis=1)

result_b=b[b.lesser_count > 0]

result_b



....clip....



y = df[df.cal== "y"]

y['lesser_count']=np.sum(np.tril(np.subtract.outer(y.col2.values,y.cal2.values),k=0)<0,axis=1)

result_y=y[y.lesser_count > 0]

result_y

And finally paste the data results (result_a,result_b,...., result_y) into a single data.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

presume you are attempting to iterate over the columns and not a crude copy/paste for each ...
here's a trivial example hopefully to help illustrate -
you'll need to adapt to your dataset.
import pandas as pd

array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

#empty dictionary to hold results

results={}
i=0
for element in array:
    results[element] = i  #do yor stuff
    i=i+1

df = pd.DataFrame(list(results.items()), columns=['column', 'value'])

print(df)
```
produces:
```
   column  value
0       a      0
1       b      1
2       c      2
3       d      3
4       e      4
5       f      5
6       g      6
...
```

